# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'session_id' in 'field list'

Tags: sql, magento

How can I solve this kind of error, after transferring my Magento files and SQL to new hosting:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'session_id' in 'field list'
```

Please see this link for the error: http://prntscr.com/3yj69u

Answer (score 2):

Ambhen, This is issue `log_visitor` table check the table structure.

Goto this check this table have  session_id columns in table 
If it is exting then you need to create log_visitor table again

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `log_visitor` (
  `visitor_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Visitor ID',
  `session_id` varchar(64) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Session ID',
  `first_visit_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'First Visit Time',
  `last_visit_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Last Visit Time',
  `last_url_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Last URL ID',
  `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Store ID',
  PRIMARY KEY (`visitor_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Log Visitors Table' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

for second issue:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `report_viewed_product_index` (
  `index_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Index Id',
  `visitor_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Visitor Id',
  `customer_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Customer Id',
  `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Product Id',
  `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Store Id',
  `added_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Added At',
  PRIMARY KEY (`index_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_REPORT_VIEWED_PRODUCT_INDEX_VISITOR_ID_PRODUCT_ID` (`visitor_id`,`product_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_REPORT_VIEWED_PRODUCT_INDEX_CUSTOMER_ID_PRODUCT_ID` (`customer_id`,`product_id`),
  KEY `IDX_REPORT_VIEWED_PRODUCT_INDEX_STORE_ID` (`store_id`),
  KEY `IDX_REPORT_VIEWED_PRODUCT_INDEX_ADDED_AT` (`added_at`),
  KEY `IDX_REPORT_VIEWED_PRODUCT_INDEX_PRODUCT_ID` (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Reports Viewed Product Index Table' AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

I hope ther are lot issue in database  ..... you  need fresh install database

Comment: Hi Amit,

I got this error

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'rmmagsde_database.report_viewed_product_index' doesn't exist

This is the screenshot1: http://prntscr.com/3ykmg2

And when I got login I see this error also.

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'rmmagsde_database.sales_flat_order' doesn't exist

This is the screenshot2: http://prntscr.com/3ykmug

Comment: Hi @Amit,

After creating the second issue i got another problem:

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'rmmagsde_database.report_compared_product_index' doesn't exist

whole screenshot: http://prntscr.com/3ykq8i

Comment: Please help! Anybody?

Comment: Hi @Amit,

It fixed the error! Thank you for your help! 

Best Regards,
Ambhen

Comment: @Amit please check here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34606694/sqlstate42s22-column-not-found-1054-unknown-column-main-table-age-in-fiel

Comment: Hey,too busy for 3-4 day. i cannot reply u .sorry for that